# How to force sync phone calendar to Outlook.com?

Tags: sync, calendars

Ok, I have weird problem: I entered one calendar entry in my phone and it is not showing in web calendar.

If I enter another calendar entry in my phone, it gets synced to Outlook.com web calendar

If I modify it, it gets propagated back to my phone.

Only one entry in my phone did not get synced and I am clueless why...

So, does someone know, how to "force push" everything from phone to the cloud?

Comment: Have you tried editing the entry to see if that pushes an update?

Comment: Now I see where I did make the error. The event is actually Facebook calendar event and not phone event. So it gets synced to phone and not to outlook. Will search for syncing between fb and outlook :